# How to repeat the same value for n times in a column based on numpy's where statement?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

A new column called Flag was created by where statement using numpy as follows.

```
import numpy as np    
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(250)
a = np.random.randint(20, size=(10,2))
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['No1', 'No2'])

df["Flag"] = np.where(df['No1'] == 0, 30, df["No2"])
```

Is it possible to repeat 30 for n times, say 3 times,  in next rows for the newly created columns like the following. Thanks for your comments.

From:

```
   No1  No2  Flag
0   14   13    13
1    0   19    30
2    5   14    14
3   16    5     5
4   10    8     8
5   16   14    14
6   10   18    18
7    2    4     4
8   19    0     0
9    4   11    11
```

To:

```
   No1  No2  Flag
0   14   13    13
1    0   19    30
2    5   14    30
3   16    5    30
4   10    8    30
5   16   14    14
6   10   18    18
7    2    4     4
8   19    0     0
9    4   11    11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over the rows (from bottom to top) and using the [`iat` locator](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html), check if the value in 'Flag' is `30`. If it is, you change the next 3 rows.

```py
# `iat` uses row and column index (like `iloc`)
# so first get the column-index of 'Flag'
flag = df.columns.get_loc('Flag')

# start from the last row, going "up" to 0
for idx in range(len(df)-1, -1, -1):
    if df.iat[idx, flag] == 30:  # check if the value is 30
        # update the 'Flag' column of the next 3 rows using `iloc`
        df.iloc[idx+1:idx+3+1, flag] = 30
```

Output:

```
   No1  No2  Flag
0   14   13    13
1    0   19    30
2    5   14    30
3   16    5    30
4   10    8    30
5   16   14    14
6   10   18    18
7    2    4     4
8   19    0     0
9    4   11    11
```

Notes:

- Reason for going bottom to top is: if it was top to bottom, each time 30 is found and 3 rows get added, it will trigger the "create 30's" continuously.
- `iloc`, `iat` use Python's list-like indexing, starting at 0, regardless of what the actual labels are
- *Unlike `loc`*, `iloc` doesn't include the end-value of a slice, just like Python lists don't. So a +1 is needed when selecting the next 3 rows.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of is to iterate it in np manually,

```
i = 0
ii = 4
temp =[]

while i < len(a):
    if a[i][0] != 0:
        temp.append(a[i][1])
    else:
        for ii in range(ii):
            temp.append(30)
        i = i + ii
    i += 1

np.c_[a, temp]
```

Doing this in pd sounds hard to me cause this is not a uniform/symmetric operation. So I suggest to do it np and this is a very robust algorithm, and allow any changes down the road. ii is the total time of 30, you said, repeat three times, means total is 4.